# Webservice publisher moving to TLS1.1

Tags: java, soap, tomcat7, apache-axis, tls1.1

We are consuming a web-service from a publisher.
Our current configuration for Java is version 1.6.
So, we have generated stubs using Axis2 and our application is hosted on tomcat7.

Now, the publisher of that webservice says that it would be moving to TLS1.1 and would stop disable the SSLv3 and TLS1.0 security protocols.

How do I ensure, that we, as a client, are compliant to this new protocol.
And, if not, what steps are needed for that.

Comment: As the client suggests a certain protocol and ciphers it understands, if the server rejects the handshake it either dosn't agree with the protocol or they couldn't agree on a certain cipher to de/encrypt data with. You could use this to setup servers in an intergration test that allow only a certain TLS protocol and then try to connect to the server. Something like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html is probably only available for browser user agents I guess. If possible you should switch to TLSv1.2 as ciphers for TLSv1/1.1 are rather unsafe

Comment: Something like https://www.howsmyssl.com/s/api.html seems to be what you are looking for I guess

Answer (score 0):

Support for **TLS 1.1** is included in the **update 111** and higher for **Java 1.6**. See this for reference: [TLS & Java](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/tls-and-java/)

You should recompile your app against the newer update and see if that works.

Also, there are issues with **TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1**, so you may need to consider to upgrade to Java 8 and start using TLS 1.2. But again, this is not a simple decision if you are supporting legacy SSL/TLS clients.